# Read the first line of a text file and store it into an array list

Tags: java, algorithm, computer-science

```
public class WeightedGraph {

    public int matrix;
    public String node;
    public int array[][];
    public ArrayList<String> nodes = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static int NEGATIVE = -1;
    private String[] record;

    public WeightedGraph(String infile){




        try {
            File newFile = new File(infile);
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(newFile);
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                String firstLine = scan.nextLine();
                record = firstLine.split(",");
                for(int i =0; i < record.length; i++) {
                    nodes.add(record[i])
                }
            }
```

I am trying to build a weighted adjacency matrix from a text file, but the first task I must do is read in the first line. I tried this method but I keep running into errors trying to add the elements of the record array into the nodes array list. Can anyone give me a simple solution to fix this?

Comment: Have you single-stepped this in your debugger to see where exactly the error occurs? What is the *exact error message* that you get? You might also search for "how to read comma separated file in java".

Comment: I have not done that yet. I am using eclipse so how would I do that. And I am not getting an error message. Whenever I run my tester, which is just an instance of the class, and I try to access the 0th element, it says that the size is 0. How would I single step this in my debugger?

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty of tutorials online that will teach you how to use the debugger in Eclipse. If your `record` array size is 0, then my first thought is that `firstLine` is blank.